# The instance member 'gantiIndex' can't be accessed as an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm trying to make a scrollable button (inkwell) scrollview where if I press the button, it will highlight the button I pressed and it will show different informations according to which button is currently highlighted. I decided to use setState to change the index but the error in this question's title came up. I tried making a separate function to use on the onTap argument but it instead showed the gantiIndex instead of the setState. Can anyone help me solve this?

Here's the code:

```
class _BiodataGuruState extends State<BiodataGuru> {
  int indexBiodata = 0;

  void gantiIndex(int index) {
    setState(() {
      indexBiodata = index;
    });
  }

  List _jenisBiodata = [
    Container(
      height: 30,
      width: 172,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          gantiIndex(0);
        },
        child: Text(
          'Riwayat Pendidikan',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1),
            letterSpacing: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

This is the error message:

```
The instance member 'gantiIndex' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is showing because you are trying to use a method in initialise variable. This is not acceptable in dart. To avoid this you can create a method which will return a list of widgets then you can use `gantiIndex` method in it. Have a look on below code.

```dart
 class _BiodataGuruState extends State<BiodataGuru> {
  int indexBiodata = 0;

  void gantiIndex(int index) {
    setState(() {
      indexBiodata = index;
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _jenisBiodata() {
    return [
      Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 172,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            gantiIndex(0);
          },
          child: Text(
            'Riwayat Pendidikan',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1),
              letterSpacing: 1,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: _jenisBiodata(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Alphamerc. I really appreciate the answer and it worked perfectly too. Hope you have a great day and be successful in your work :D